# installing pip on python 2.7.8 on windows

Tags: python, pip, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to install the module pip for python 2.7.8, the one that arcGIS installs for you.

I am using the bootstrap method of installing pip and I am running into an error when I run `get-pip.py` with Command Prompt.

I get the following error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):   File
"c:\users\vlaw\appdata\local\temp\tmpzamnrk\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py",
line 122 InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not
available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately
and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a
newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a
problem confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
verify failed - skipping Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
c:\esripyfldr\arcgis10.3 Collecting setuptools

Warning (from warnings module):   File
"c:\users\vlaw\appdata\local\temp\tmpzamnrk\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py",
line 122 InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not
available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately
and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a
newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/: There
was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
verify failed - skipping [31m  Could not find a version that
satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
```

I am using internet provided by my company. Do you think the firewall is the reason it's giving me the error?

Comment: Why are you using 2.7 version ? Is there any specific purpose for using it?. You can use versions from  3.0. It has pip installed by default in it. So there won't be any problem.

Comment: My python was installed by the software ArcGIS. Python 2.7.8 is the only version compatible with the software. idk.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set proxies as you are inside firewall and installing files form outside firewall.

**Ubuntu**:

```
export http_proxy="http://<<username>>:<<password>>@<<proxy server>>:<<proxy_port>>"
export https_proxy="https://<<username>>:<<password>>@<<proxy server>>:<<proxy_port>>"
```

**Windows**:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<<username>>:<<password>>@<<proxy server>>:<<proxy_port>>
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://<<username>>:<<password>>@<<proxy server>>:<<proxy_port>>
```

Comment: Do I have to change the username, password, and proxy_port when i run the command?

Comment: @VincentLaw Yes, that is what `< >` typically means.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
and then run `python get-pip.py`.

If this doesn't work use `python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/`.

Hope this helps.